# Coloring a plot partially in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I am going to plot a parameter called force in terms of frequency.
my plot is going to be a semilogy plot ( I mean in "Y" direction it should be logarithmic) but as I know force is negative in some frequencies so in logarithmic plot it can not be drawn.
All in all, the think I want is that I want to draw the force semilogarithmic and have the negative parts also in graph in a different color.
  semilogy(frequency,abs(force(2800,:)))
I don't know how to change the colors of negative parts.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [logical indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
freq = 0:1000; % frequency vector
force = 10*rand(size(freq))-5; % some random data between -5 and +5
semilogy(freq(force>0),force(force>0),'b-',freq(force<0),abs(force(force<0)),'r-')
```

which gives the following plot:

[image]

Comment: but the problem is here that force is a 2D Matrix it means I need to determine the phase of force to plot. as   force(2800,frequency) I meant that draw the force in terms of frequency in its 2800th phase angle.

Comment: You didn't say `force` was a 2D-matrix in your question

Comment: so you do not have any suggestion for 2D?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what it is that you're trying to do. If `force` is a 2D-matrix, than `force(2800,:)` is a vector that can be plotted against `frequency` as per my answer. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the best way to ask a question and the best chance to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is basically the same as [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534929/3599179) but with a little more detail.

Take the following sample dataset:

```
freq = linspace(0, 2*pi);
force = 1e6*sinc(freq);
```

`force` is a vector that contains positive and negative values, therefore, if we use [`semilogy`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html) with this data we will get a logarithmic plot of the positive values only (as you mentioned):

```
>> semilogy(freq, force, 'b*');
Warning: Negative data ignored
```

[image: semilogy positive values only]

If you want to plot the absolute value of the negative values, you can use [logical indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) to find the indices of the negative values like this:

```
idx = force < 0;
```

And then plot these values in red color on the same axes:

```
hold on;
semilogy(freq(idx), abs(force(idx)), 'r*');
```

[image: semilogy positive and negative values]

You can also use this syntax to produce the same result:

```
semilogy(freq, force, 'b*', freq(idx), abs(force(idx)), 'r*');
```